# PUT request with unbuffered RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, requestfactory, spring-web

Using Spring `RestTemplate`, buffer request body set to false and empty body

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(60_000);
RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplate(requestFactory);
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), Void.class);
```

I receive `411 - Length Required` status code in response.
For some reason Spring RestTemplate does not put `Content-Length: 0` header on the request.

In case I comment `requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);` line, it works perfect. But I need it for sending large files.

UPD: Looking into debug logs showed us, that request doesn't contain  `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Can you please add values of parameters to `restTemplate.exchange` call?

Comment: Update to HttpMethod.PUT. But other parametres are not significant. uri - some rackspace service uri, httpHeaders are single authorization token.

Comment: The problem is, that request hasn't header Content-Length in it. Checked it with debug resttemplate logging.

Comment: I am most interested in how you read and send file.

Comment: Maybe http client uses `chunked encoding`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding . What is size of a file you send?

Comment: the problem, I try to send big file and empty request via the same restTemplate. With notnull request everything is ok, put this unbuf resttemplate unable to send empty put request

Comment: Did you try RestTemplate with different http client? Like Apache HTTP?

Comment: As result I use two different restTemplate for two types of operations (for large files not buffered, and buffered for others)

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway I managed to replicate the issue that time and found Apache http client does not have it. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to replicate your issue with `RestTemplate` and `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. After switching  to [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) the issue is gone.

Here you are how I configured `RestTemplate`:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
    .create()
    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
factory.setBufferRequestBody(false);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
restTemplate.exchange(......);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I haven't solved it with RestTemplate. I solved it in such way:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("you_url");
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(tempFile.toFile(), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, "file_name");
        builder.addPart("parameter_name", fileBody);
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile)) {
            //....
        }
```